# How to get top and bottom margins in emacs

Tags: user-interface, emacs

how would I get top and bottom margins (like the left and right fringe) when using emacs? I find that having the text start right at the top of the screen is a little uncomfortable when I'm writing or reviewing large blocks of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find a top-and-bottom-only margin setting, but there is a frame parameter `internal-border-width` which might be sufficient.  You would set it for the current frame like so:

```
(set-frame-parameter nil 'internal-border-width 10)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sean. This pushes the bar for the minibuffer window up which then clutters up the bottom of the window. Not quite right but definitely gets me closer.